# Scala iText PDF: Type Mismatch Error with ImageResource and ITextFSImage

Tags: scala, itext

I'm working on a Scala project where I'm using the iText library to generate PDFs. I have a custom class ElabUserAgent that extends ITextUserAgent, and I'm trying to create an ImageResource from an image using Image.getInstance. However, I'm encountering a type mismatch error when trying to pass the com.itextpdf.text.Image object to ImageResource. The error message I'm getting is:

```
 Class com.lowagie.text.Image not found - continuing with a stub.
 [error]         val fsImage = new ITextFSImage(itextImage)
```

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Image
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFSImage
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextOutputDevice
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextUserAgent
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf._
import org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.ImageResource
import org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource
import play.api.Environment
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc.Result
import play.api.mvc.Results
import play.twirl.api.Html
private class ElabUserAgent(
environment: Environment,
  logger: Logger,
  outputDevice: ITextOutputDevice,
) extends ITextUserAgent(outputDevice) {

override def getImageResource(uri: String): ImageResource =
environment
  .resourceAsStream(uri)
  .map { stream =>
    val itextImage = Image.getInstance(IOUtils.toByteArray(stream))
      val fsImage = new ITextFSImage(itextImage) 
    new ImageResource(fsImage)
  }
  .getOrElse {
    logger.error(s"Could not find '${uri}' while generating PDF")
    super.getImageResource(uri)
  }
```

}

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

Comment: It looks like the `org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf` classes you use depend on the ancient `com.lowagie` iText versions (anything before version 5) while you use a somewhat newer (albeit still old) version 5.x.